# ESLint: TypeError: this.libOptions.parse is not a function

Tags: node.js, eslint, webstorm, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I was getting started with Next.js on WebStorm 2022.2.1 Build #WS-222.3739.57.
I created a new Next.js project with TypeScript enabled, and that's all.

The error is shown below:

```
TypeError: this.libOptions.parse is not a function

TypeError: this.libOptions.parse is not a function
    at ESLint8Plugin.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:139:64)
    at step (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:44:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:25:53)
    at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:19:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:15:12)
    at ESLint8Plugin.invokeESLint (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:133:16)
    at ESLint8Plugin.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:120:44)
    at step (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:44:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint8-plugin.js:25:53)
Process finished with exit code -1
```

My Node.js version is v16.15.1, and the ESLint version is 8.23.0.

This is what my devDependencies look like;

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.7.13",
    "@types/react": "18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "prisma": "^4.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.2"
  }
```

My *.eslintrc.json* file:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-57089](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57089/ESLint823-TypeError-thislibOptionsparse-is-not-a-function), and it is fixed in 2022.2.2 [preview build](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/WEB-A-11/WebStorm-EAP).

The issue is caused by the changes introduced in ESLint 8.23 (offending upstream commit: [View on GitHub](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/3e5839ecae96aecfbc1ac9526e88e0105e671032#diff-358c9491edc00f0db6f2f3c317df9aa932135803481b86c9289bd56bf8af0622L66)). Downgrading ESLint to 8.22.x or earlier (with `npm install eslint@8.22.0 --save-exact`) should help.

Comment: The preview build in the link for Apple silicon is not working as of now.
Fix: add `-cdn` to URL: https://download-cdn.jetbrains.com/webstorm/WebStorm-222.4167.9-aarch64.dmg

Comment: This does not just occur in ESLint versions 8.23, I am seeing this while on ESlint 8.19

Comment: 2022.2.2 has been released as stable now.

Comment: Who can save the guy that the subscription can only upgrade to 2022.1.x, and has to work on the project use ESLint v8.34

Answer (score 104):

If you are looking for a temporary fix, you can "pin" `ESLint` version to 8.22.0 in your `package.json` set it to:

```
"eslint": "8.22.0"
```

After that update your project to get back to 8.22 instead of 8.23, i.e.

- remove node_modules folder
- clean package-lock.json (by removing it too)
- run `npm install`

Or in one command:

```
rm -rf node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm install
```

Let's hope this issue will be resolved soon

Comment: Or a slightly shorter one-liner: `rm -fr node_modules package-lock.json; npm install`

Answer (score 74):

My friends, if you are using **Webstorm** or any **Jetbrains** product, you can use this pattern in your **eslint settings** and it will be fixed for **EVER**.

1. Settings (or "Alt + Shift + S")
2. Search "eslint"
3. Choose "Automatic ESLint configuration"
4. Then replace the pattern below with the exist one:

   ```
   "**/*.(js|ts|jsx|tsx|html|vue)"
   ```

Comment: That fixed my Webstorm (2022.2.1) issue with my NextJS 13 project thank you.

Comment: This fixed my issue, are there any downsides to this approach?

Comment: @Dejan, As far as I checked and using it for a few years, no.

Comment: You are the MVP, my bro

Answer (score 32):

For me, the other solutions didn't work.

A simple WebStorm update to version 2022.2.3 solved it.

Comment: For me both changing the ESLint version and updating WebStorm worked in two distinct cases this month. So seems like we can choose either solution

Comment: Worked like a charm with no other change than the ide update. I use PHPStorm btw.

Comment: I was already at eslint 8.27.0 and had the issue. Upgrading WebStorm helped.

Comment: It's incredible but it's true, just the same problem, and updating to the last one (2022.2.4 in my case) the issue was solved.

Answer (score 30):

I was having the same issue as well with ESLint and [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm).

Here is the solution:

```
yarn add eslint@8.22.0 --save-exact

npm install eslint@8.22.0 --save-exact
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

This solves it.

```
npm install eslint@8.22.0 --save-exact
```

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router": "^6.3.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "8.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1"
    }
}
```